# Rendering multiple Instagram feeds as one within SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app

Hoping some of my fellow SharePoint guru's can point me in the right direction.

We have multiple Brands, each brand has their own Instagram account and posts their own content. We would like to render all of the Brands into one feed on our company intranet. Thus keeping our internal users up to date without having to navigate to each.

We currently have a solution that requires you to pick from a drop down and only renders one at a time.

Need to display:

- Brand
- Text of the post
- Picture/image

Answer (score 0):

This is something i would solve with Server side code.

If this is placed in a central location it might be worth having a cache for this, and reading 3 feeds for each request might be a lot if done from all clients. Server in this case does not mean sharepoint, it could be an IIS process that merges these 3 feeds and exposes them as one.

To be honest i would move something like this into azure and expose the merged feed there somehow... You dont need a whole server for this feature and its unsecured data - perfect azure usecase. You also have access to some additional features like stream analytics for sentiment checks

I know overkill ;)
But have a look here... Replace your "WPF app" with a webservice endpoint and display the result in a sharepoint Webpart...
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-twitter-sentiment-analysis-trends

edit: An RSS feed would be cached by SharePoint by default So your actual load on the endpoint would be fairly low

Answer (score -2):

Earlier I also had the same requirement.

Just use this web part https://github.com/thenikhilk/sharepoint-instagram-feed.

No need for tokens, registration or any third party sign-in, just username you want to embed.